# Объединение данных в SQL Firebird 1.5

Tags: sql, firebird

Имеются три таблицы: Заявки, Исполнители, Заявители.
У одной заявки может быть несколько Исполнителей и несколько Заявителей (Созаявители).
Делаю запрос:

```
SELECT Заявители.Имя AS Заявитель, Заявки.Номер AS Заявка, 
(Исполнители.Имя || ' - ' || Исполнитель.Должность) AS Исполнители
FROM Заявители, Заявки, Исполнители 
WHERE (UPPER(Заявители.Имя) LIKE '%ИВАН%') AND 
(Заявители.ID = Заявки.ID) AND 
(Заявки.ID = Исполнители.ID)
```

Получаю результат вида:

```
Заявитель                 |Заявка    |Исполнители                                                                        
--------------------------|----------|--------------------------
Глазков Евгений Иванович  |271       |Пяткин А.Ю. - Должность1                             
Кельзин Владимир Иванович |28        |Коптев В.В. - Должность2
Кельзин Владимир Иванович |28        |Насыров А.А. - Должность1
```

Как можно доработать запрос, чтобы результат был такого вида:

```
Заявитель                 |Заявка    |Исполнители                                                                        
--------------------------|----------|--------------------------
Глазков Евгений Иванович  |271       |Пяткин А.Ю. - Должность1                             
Кельзин Владимир Иванович |28        |Коптев В.В. - Должность2; Насыров А.А. - Должность1
```

Comment: Начиная с версии 2.1 есть LIST()

Comment: К сожалению версия 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написать хранимую процедуру, которая будет по ID заявки пробегать циклом всех исполнителей и собирать их в строку.

Для созаявителей придется писать еще одну процедуру. Или если оба списка чаще всего выбираются вместе, что оба цикла можно поместить в одну процедуру.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Решил задачу обработкой на стороне клиента.